# Integrating Instant Markup view controller more directly in iOS 11 app

Tags: pdf, ios11

I have an app that shows PDFs, and I'd love to let my users markup PDFs from inside the app.  In iOS 11, using the `UIDocumentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu` method for my PDF, I get a "Create PDF" option which presents a view controller with the ability to draw on the PDF (Instant Markup).  If the user then chooses to save the PDF to iCloud, then the original file I displayed is overwritten with the changes.

This feature is pretty hard for my users to find and use, is there a way to hook a UIButton up so that it opens this view controller directly?